# How to convert from std::io::Bytes to &[u8]

Tags: rust

I am trying to write the contents of an HTTP Response to a file.

```
extern crate reqwest;

use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut resp = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").unwrap();
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());

    // Write contents to disk.
    let mut f = File::create("download_file").expect("Unable to create file");
    f.write_all(resp.bytes());
}
```

But I get the following compile error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
12 |     f.write_all(resp.bytes());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &[u8], found struct `std::io::Bytes`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
              found type `std::io::Bytes<reqwest::Response>`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot. Checking [the docs for `io::Bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Bytes.html), there are no appropriate methods. That's because `io::Bytes` is an iterator that returns things byte-by-byte so there may not even *be* a single underlying slice of data.

It you only had `io::Bytes`, you would need to [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) the iterator into a `Vec`:

```
let data: Result<Vec<_>, _> = resp.bytes().collect();
let data = data.expect("Unable to read data");
f.write_all(&data).expect("Unable to write data");
```

However, in most cases you have access to the type that implements `Read`, so you could instead use [`Read::read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end):

```
let mut data = Vec::new();
resp.read_to_end(&mut data).expect("Unable to read data");
f.write_all(&data).expect("Unable to write data");
```

In this specific case, you can use [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) to directly copy from the `Request` to the file because `Request` implements [`io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) and `File` implements [`io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html):

```
extern crate reqwest;

use std::io;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut resp = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").unwrap();
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());

    // Write contents to disk.
    let mut f = File::create("download_file").expect("Unable to create file");
    io::copy(&mut resp, &mut f).expect("Unable to copy data");
}
```